# What is the order of multiple pre/post incrementations in one line equation in JAVA?

Tags: java, java-8, unary-operator

I have this piece of code in JAVA 8:

`int x=3;
 int y = --x + x++ + --x ;
 System.out.print("y: " + y + " x: "+x);`

As I understand it should be split like this:

1. y = 2 + x++ + --x; x = 2
2. y = 2 + 2 + --x; x = 2
3. y = 2 + 2 + 1; x = 1
4. y = 5; x = 2

And it prints `y: 6 x: 2`
What is the order of operation in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the way `pre` and `post` increments work, it gets evaluated like this:

```
 1. y = --x + x++ + --x ;
 2. y = 2 + (2)++ + --(3);
 3. y = 2 + 2 + 2;
 4. y = 6
```

After 2 decrements and 1 increment, `x` becomes 2.

Comment: third operation is also predecrementation
in case of `y = --x  +  --x`
y would be 3 and x would be 1.
why in this example second --x is initialized with 3 not 2?

Comment: Yes, so 2 (pre) decrements and 1 (post) increments result in 1 decrement evantually, changing the value of `x` to 2.

Comment: I understand why final x is 2. The thing that I don't get is, why second (pre) is not called after first one giving there `2 +2 + 1`

Comment: Because it gets evaluated from left to right. Position of `x` supercedes `pre` or `post` increments.